# Powershell replace entire line in text file

Tags: regex, powershell

I have this text file *text.txt*

```
aaa
#wsuri=myuri
ccc
```

and this command working OK

```
> "#wsuri=myuri" -replace '^#wsuri=myuri$','bbb'
bbb
```

But, if I try the same on a file:

```
> (Get-Content .\text.txt -raw) -replace '^#wsuri=myuri$','bbb'
aaa
#wsuri=myuri
ccc
```

What should I do for the regex to work on a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Due to use of [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) `-Raw`, your input string is a *multiline* string**, but the **`^` and `$` [regex anchors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#anchors) *by default* only operate on the start and end of the *string as a whole***, not on individual lines.

You have two **options**:

Include the [`Multiline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions#System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_Multiline) regex option, which makes `^` and `$` match the start and end of individual *lines* instead; its inline form - which must be placed at the start of the regex - is `(?m)`:

```
(Get-Content .\text.txt -Raw) -replace '(?m)^#wsuri=myuri$','bbb'
```

Alternatively, for (slower) line-by-line input processing, which outputs an *array* of lines, simply omit `-Raw`:

```
(Get-Content .\text.txt) -replace '^#wsuri=myuri$','bbb'
```

Note that [`-replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375), like all PowerShell comparison-like operators, accepts an *array* as the LHS, in which case the operation is performed *on each element*, which in this case means that each line from the input file is processed separately.

Answer (score -1):

Try Setting `set-content` to the same file path:

```
((Get-Content -path .\text.txt -Raw) -replace '^#wsuri=myuri$','bbb') | Set-Content -Path .\text.txt
```

Comment: The problem isn't writing back to the same file, the problem is that `^` and `$` don't match _line_ beginnings and endings in a _multiline_ string  (obtained with `Get-Content -Raw`) by default, so the `-replace` operation didn't work.